# Heroku app won't redirect unlike when it's running on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I've been building and running a web app on my localhost. Everything was working fine after I carried out all the test to make sure everything was working fine. I finally decided to deploy the web app on heroku, where I wanted to add extra content on the landing page through by using the admin section.

Now, I face the problem when I try to register a new user. After I've clicked the register link and fill out all the fields. The site redirects me to a blank page displaying '500 | Server Error.' instead of redirecting me to the login page where I can access the website and add content. This is an image of the page which it redirects me to. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Tpq.png) instead of redirecting me to a page like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdEIT.png). Can some please guide me on a way of how to solve this problem? If you want to try out the site, here's the link. http://lifeisspiritual.herokuapp.com/register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in production mode, you have to set it to development in .env, then you will see the error stack trace. I don't think you can solve it without this change.